# Story about people who travel through desert, have airships, consisting of two books

Tags: story-identification

The story is about people that travel through a desert to a city, I remember there being two nations, one of them I think was called The Fiery or Faery cant quite remember, I do recall airships, and what seems to be a city that had long forgotten aspects to it that the visitors discover. There were two books. I have tried in vain to google with no results. The books were lost in a house move some years ago

Answer (score 12):

This is [Stephen Lawhead](http://stephenlawhead.com/)'s two-book [Empyrion](http://stephenlawhead.com/empyrion.html) cycle. The desert people were called the *Fieri*.

The Cynetics Corporation discovers a wormhole near Earth, and sends a colony ship through it. Shortly after, they send another ship through, carrying Orion Treet, a historian, to document the colony's growth. However, passing through the wormhole Treet's ship experiences a time dilation effect, meaning that when he reaches the colony of Empyrion he is in the future. (Quite how far forward he travels is never made clear IIRC, but I seem to think it's at least 1 000 years). The Fieri were a group cast out as a result of a civil war several hundred years before Treet's arrival.

Comment: What a coincidence I am actually reading this book right now :p