# Domed Colony trilogy

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization

I am looking for a trilogy - the basic plot revolves around a man who ends up on a transport to a domed colony. The colony has evolved its own complicated parochial hierarchy, the colonial mission and technology is forgotten. The protagonist is first tortured in a sensory deprivation cell, then released, somehow joins up with a 'resistance' rebel underground who manage to escape the dome on skimmers...outside they discover that they can breathe the air. they travel across a desert and find a city of people who left the domed colony at some point in the past.

I seem to remember the books being an unusual genre for that author but cant seem to remember the name.

Any ideas would be appreciated - this is one of the best space novels I've read and is worth checking out - I want to add it to my library

Comment: Duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26902/story-about-people-who-travel-through-desert-have-airships-consisting-of-two-b

Answer (score 5):

Per @PhilPursglove's comment, this is almost certainly The [Empyrion Saga](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0745918727) by Stephen R. Lawhead.

[This review](http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/379263743) on Goodreads (of the second book "[Siege of Dome](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/353792.The_Siege_of_Dome?from_search=true)") mentions a considerable number of your plot points;

- Domed cities - check
- Patriarchy - check
- Hero tortured in a sensory deprivation chamber - check
- Escapes and joins resistance - check
- Travel across a desert - check
- Set in a domed city - check
- Trilogy - Actually it was a duology but that's close enough